# having distorted image in VGA with FPGA board

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, vga

I'm using spartan 3E-100 CP132 fpga board to display a basic plus image on a monitor. I have tried using 800x600 72 hz and 640x480 60 Hz but I always get a distorted vertical lines. Is it because the on board oscillator is silicon but not crystal so it's not precise enough? is there a way to avoid this? I've put the image I get[image]

Comment: That's a lot of short-term timing jitter. I doubt that you can attribut this to the oscillator alone. But without more details about your setup, it's impossible to suggest a solution.

Comment: by my setup if you mean the monitor it is ag neovo f419 and the board is digilent basys2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's because you are using the "silicon" oscillator.

The basys2 board also provides a socket for a crystal oscillator.
If you plug in a crystal oscillator and use its clock signal the jitter is gone and the VGA image will be fine. I have tried it myself.

BTW: The manual tells you about that:

> The primary silicon oscillator is flexible and
>   inexpensive, but it lacks the frequency stability of
>   a crystal oscillator. Some circuits that drive a
>   VGA monitor may realize a slight improvement in
>   image stability by using a crystal oscillator
>   installed in the IC6 socket. For these applications,
>   a 25MHz (or 50MHz) crystal oscillator, available
>   from any catalog distributor, is recommended

("may realize a slight improvement" is a strong understatement)

See page 3 in [the Basys2 manual](http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/BASYS2/Basys2_rm.pdf).